# What is the "Community Bulletin"?

Tags: support

What is the use of the "Community Bulletin" and how is it decided what goes in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bulletin is intended to allow promotion of 'useful' stuff. As such, it works in part like the older sidebar, picking up 'active' meta topics automatically so that they get shown to people who don't visit meta very often. At the same time, the moderators can add a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to meta questions, which will 'promote' them in the Bulletin.

The Bulletin can also be used to promote 'Community Events'. We use this for the 'Answer the Unanswered' sessions and for the chat-based interviews. These events can only be added to the Bulletin by one of the moderators: they don't have to be linked to chat sessions, but that is how we've used that to date. The idea here is that the Bulletin is less intrusive than the banner that mods can add for 'system messages', and also the Bulletin works better for a longer promotion period.

As Andrew Stacey points out, the Bulletin also picks up new blog posts from the [TeX-sx blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com), and they show up for 7 days. (Previously, these were shown at the top of the page, but the appearance was poor and you could not see the titles.)

Comment: It also flags new blog posts.